# Java - Преобразование строки символов в unicode коды

Tags: java, unicode

Необходимо получить коды символов в Юникоде. За эталон можно взять фразу:

> гайдай какой-то
>
> 0433 0430 0439 0434 0430 0439 0020 043a 0430 043a 043e 0439 002d 0442 043e

Коды совпадают с кодами [из этой таблицы](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#0433).

Как произвести такое преобразование?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А скастить `char` в `int` не пробовали?

```
String s = "привет мир";
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    int code = (int)c;
    System.out.format("%04X ", code);
}
```

[выдаёт](http://ideone.com/A0NqzC)

```
043F 0440 0438 0432 0435 0442 0020 043C 0438 0440
```

Comment: Поражаюсь, да вы прямо Java - гуру!

Comment: @Flippy: А ещё я на машинке вышивать умею! И крестиком (ц)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо!

Comment: @PaxExterminatus: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Получение кодов UNICODE в строке

```
String prContentFormatHex = "";
for (char c : prContent.toCharArray()) {
    int code = (int)c;
    prContentFormatHex += String.format("%04X ", code);
}
```

Получение кодов GSM7 (GSM 7-bit default alphabet (Hexadecimal)) в строке. **Только для латиницы!**

[Appendix: GSM 7-bit Default Alphabet Table (with Character Codes of ISO 8859 Latin 1)](http://www.developershome.com/sms/gsmAlphabet.asp)

```
if (prContentFormatCoding == 0) { //Кодирование для GSM7
    for (char c : prContent.toCharArray()) {
        int code = (int)c;
        prContentFormatHex += String.format("%X ", code);
    }
}
```

Примеры отображения строк в кодах UNICODE

- Hi My Name Is Slim Shady

> 0048 0069 0020 004D 0079 0020 004E 0061 006D 0065 0020 0049 0073 0020
>   0053 006C 0069 006D 0020 0053 0068 0061 0064 0079

- В рот мне ноги, быстро!

> 0412 0020 0440 043E 0442 0020 043C 043D 0435 0020 043D 043E 0433 0438
>   002C 0020 0431 044B 0441 0442 0440 043E 0021

Примеры отображения строк в кодах GSM7

- Hi My Name Is

> 48 69 20 4D 79 20 4E 61 6D 65 20 49 73